# Combine two arrays and show in a table

Tags: php, html, arrays, duplicates, html-table

I have two arrays in php:

```
$kolicina =Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 7 [2] => 5 [3] => 7 )

$array =Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [kodProizvoda] => 2 
        [imeProizvoda] => Fanta 
        [jedinica] => litra 
        [cijena] => 7 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [kodProizvoda] => 1 
        [imeProizvoda] => Coca Cola 
        [jedinica] => litra 
        [cijena] => 15 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [kodProizvoda] => 3 
        [imeProizvoda] => Sprite 
        [jedinica] => litra 
        [cijena] => 17 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [kodProizvoda] => 5 
        [imeProizvoda] => Juice 
        [jedinica] => litra 
        [cijena] => 14 
    ) 
)
```

how to show in table like this:

```
kolicina | kodproizvoda | imeProizvoda |jedinica | cijena 
   5     |      2       | fanta        | litra   |   7
   7     |      1       | coca cola    |litra    | 15
```

and so on...

I tried with function arrray combine :

```
$brojac = 0;
foreach (array_combine($kolicina, $array) as $code => $name) {
    $name= implode("<td>", $name);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> <input type="number" id="'.$brojac.'" class="kol" name="kolicina[]" value="'.$code.'"></td>';
    echo '<td> '.$name.'</td>';
    echo '<td id="iznostbl'.$brojac.'"> </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $brojac++;
}
```

But this function remove duplicates from kolicina. How to get good html table with duplicates with the same value kolicina?

Comment: Try [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine). Just iterate over one of the arrays using *foreach* and use the index (in your case: `$code`) to find the associated elements of the other array. See the example below.

You can also just use the iterator index `$code` in place of the variable you set outside the loop and incremented after each iteration (i.e. `$brojac`) because it also starts at the first index (i.e. 0) and it goes through the last index (i.e. length of the array - 1).

```
foreach ($array as $code => $name) {
    $name= implode("</td><td>", $name);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> <input type="number" id="'.$kolicina[$code].'" class="kol" name="kolicina[]" value="'.$code.'">'.$kolicina[$code].'</td>';
    echo '<td> '.$name.'</td>';
    echo '<td id="iznostbl'.$code.'"> </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Take a look at [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jvsq-k723).

**Edit:**
You could add some logic to handle cases where the two arrays might have differing lengths - if that was the case, you might not want to show the table, in case there would be missing data (or at least an error could arise when attempting to find an element in the array `$kolicina` that doesn't exist). For this, compare the values of [`count()`](https://www.php.net/count) on each array.

```
if (count($array) == count($kolicina)) {
    //show the table
}
else {
    //show a message about missing data? or some other action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_combine` is used when you have an array of keys and an array of values, and you want to create a new array that has the corresponding keys and values. `$kolicina` is not keys, so there's no reason to use this. You lose duplicates because an associative array can only have one element with the same key.

You just need to iterate over the array indexes, and then access elements from both arrays:

```
foreach ($kolicina as $brojac => $code) {
    $row = $array[$brojac];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> <input type="number" id="'.$brojac.'" class="kol" name="kolicina[]" value="'.$code.'"></td>';
    echo "<td>{$row['kodProizvoda'}</td><td>{$row['imeProizvoda'}</td><td>{$row['jedinica'}</td><td>{$row['cijena'}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
```